# How 'Logjam' attack affects openID since it uses Diffie-Hellman key exchange method?

Tags: java, security, openid, openid4java

According to the [1] Diffie-Hellman key exchange get affected by this and openID uses this to establish an association. So how this going to affect openID?

[1] - http://thenextweb.com/insider/2015/05/20/theres-a-new-problem-with-ssl-called-logjam-heres-what-you-need-to-know/

Comment: see your other post: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/89756/how-logjam-attack-affects-openid-since-it-uses-diffie-hellman-key-exchange-met